# SQL Server scalar function returns VARCHAR truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I created a scalar function in SQL Server 2008 R2 that returns a varchar (4000).
This varchar (4000) is the result of concatenating multiple rows and multiple columns of a table.
I will use this function in a select source for a report.
The details are the products with the quantity and price of a particular sale.

The problem happens when I use the select function.
The result is truncated.
He was to return 13 rows and only returns 5.
If I use the print command within the sql management studio function returns
the 13 lines.

What to do for the function to return the correct number lines?

```
print dbo.fnReturnProducts ('{25899A98-5E68-E641-8C9D-7F341F17F2EF}')  -- returns 13 lines
select dbo.fnReturnProducts ('{25899A98-5E68-E641-8C9D-7F341F17F2EF}') -- returns 5 lines

alter function [dbo].[fnReturnProducts](@OrderId uniqueidentifier) returns varchar(4000)
begin 

declare @Products as varchar(4000)
declare @ProductName as varchar(43)
declare @ProductOrder as varchar(3)
declare @Quantity varchar(30)
declare @UnitPrice varchar(30)
declare @TotalPrice varchar(30)

select @Products = ''

DECLARE aux_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select
    ProductName as ProductName,
    dbo.FormatNumber (ProductOrder, 0, '(', 0) as ProductOrder,
    dbo.FormatNumber (Quantity, 2, '', 0) as Quantity,
    dbo.FormatNumber (UnitPrice , 2, '$', 0) as UnitPrice,
    dbo.FormatNumber (Quantity * UnitPrice, 2, '$', 0) as TotalPrice    
from    vwOrderDetails
Where OrderId = @OrderId
order BY vwOrderDetails.ProductOrder


OPEN aux_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM aux_cursor 
INTO 
    @ProductName,
    @ProductOrder,
    @Quantity,
    @UnitPrice,
    @TotalPrice


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    if len(@Products) > 0 
    begin
        select @Products = @Products + char(10)
    end 
    select @Products = @Products +  '(' + @ProductOrder + ') ' + @Quantity + ' - ' + @ProductName  + ' a ' + @UnitPrice + ' = ' + @TotalPrice

   FETCH NEXT FROM aux_cursor 
   INTO 
    @ProductName,
    @ProductOrder,
    @Quantity,
    @UnitPrice,
    @TotalPrice

END

CLOSE aux_cursor
DEALLOCATE aux_cursor

RETURN @Products

end


go
```

Comment: Is it truncated when calling from outside of SSMS? Curious to check if it's just the results window that's truncating it...

Comment: print dbo.fnReturnProducts ('{25899A98-5E68-E641-8C9D-7F341F17F2EF}')  -- returns 13 lines

Comment: No. Inside SSMS and from application. When i use select the results return truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select dbo.fnReturnProducts ('{25899A98-5E68-E641-8C9D-7F341F17F2EF}')  into #tablename
select * from #tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a answer, but the results from SSMS (and application).
See the difference: only print and select commands.
Inside the application i use select (my problem).

```
print dbo.fnReturnProducts ('{25899A98-5E68-E641-8C9D-7F341F17F2EF}')  -- returns 13 lines

(1) 1.00 - MAC INST PARATI GAL/CAIPIRA 85GR            a $.75 = $.75
(2) 1.00 - MAC INST PARATI CAR/LEG.85GR                a $.75 = $.75
(3) 1.00 - MAC INST PARATI GAL/CAIPIRA 85GR            a $.75 = $.75
(4) 1.00 - TRINK TANGERINA 35GR                        a $.69 = $.69
(5) 1.00 - TRINK TANGERINA 35GR                        a $.69 = $.69
(6) 1.00 - MAC ORSI BAM.OVOS PARAFUSO 500GR            a $1.56 = $1.56
(7) 1.00 - MAC INST PARATI CAR/LEG.85GR                a $.75 = $.75
(8) 1.00 - ORSI ACHOC PO 400GR                         a $2.16 = $2.16
(9) 1.00 - ORSI ACHOC PO 400GR                         a $2.16 = $2.16
(10) 1.00 - BISC.PANCO ROSQ NATA 500G                   a $3.53 = $3.53
(11) 1.00 - ST PROTEX ERVA DOCE 90GR                    a $1.76 = $1.76
(12) 1.00 - OLEO SOJA CORCOVADO 900ML               UN  a $3.59 = $3.59
(13) 1.00 - OLEO SOJA CORCOVADO 900ML               UN  a $3.59 = $3.59

select dbo.fnReturnProducts ('{25899A98-5E68-E641-8C9D-7F341F17F2EF}') -- returns 5 lines

(1) 1.00 - MAC INST PARATI GAL/CAIPIRA 85GR            a $.75 = $.75
(2) 1.00 - MAC INST PARATI CAR/LEG.85GR                a $.75 = $.75
(3) 1.00 - MAC INST PARATI GAL/CAIPIRA 85GR            a $.75 = $.75
(4) 1.00 - TRINK TANGERINA 35GR
```